# How do I make sure my http://ec2-**-**-***.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com points to my domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, dns

Here's what I've done so far:

I created a free EC2 instance (used an AMI by bitnami for wordpress)

I set up a wordpress theme on it.

I bought a domain using namecheap.

I pointed that domain to the Public IP and Public DNS of my EC2 instance, by creating an `A record` and `CNAME record`.

So now when I enter `domain.com` in my browser, it opens and resolves correctly.

But, when I put `http://ec2-**-**-***.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com` in my url bar, it opens up to the same landing page, but does not redirect to `domain.com`.

So this means that there are two URLs which can access my website, I only want one.

I want `http://ec2-**-**-***.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com` to open up -> `domain.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to configure your web server to issue a redirect response if the domain doesn't match the one you want.

Comment: I really appreciate you answering, but could you dumb it down for me, or point me to a tutorial? @mark

Comment: I assume you're using Apache web server, since you are using Wordpress. So you would use a rewrite rule for this. Something like what they are doing in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086876/apache-rewrite-force-https-and-name-of-server-not-ip

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code snippet in `wordpress-htaccess.conf` located at `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^3\.4\.81\.127
RewriteRule (.*) https://readosapien.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ec2-3-4-81-127\.ap-south-1\.compute\.amazonaws\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://readosapien.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace the IP address and ec2-ip

And Hurrah!

**PS:** This solution is most applicable if you're using AWS lightsail.